# WPF: Deactivating the button animations

Tags: c#, wpf, button

I'm designing an UI atm and have the problem that the button animations don't fit the style of my Program and I would rather just change the colour.

My problem is: I just cant find a way do deactivate the animation that appears when you hover about or click a button :(
Is it even possible ?

Comment: Show more details like code or xaml.Do you declare your animation in xaml or code.And you can definitly deactivate this by stop the storyboard

Comment: I just wanted a general answer for any button :)) i will look into this storyboard thing, thanks.

Comment: You can most certainly do this.  Just create your own style by modifying the code given by MS here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753328%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: "Button Styles and Templates" sounds exactly like what i have searched for :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an image animation which is similar to an Button.

```
<Image Width="20" Height="20" Source="image\close.png" 
                     ToolTip="close"
                   Opacity="0.5" Canvas.Left="720" Canvas.Top="3" 
                   MouseLeftButtonDown="Close_MouseLeftButtonDown">
                <Image.RenderTransform>
                    <RotateTransform x:Name="imgTransform"
                                     CenterX="10"
                                     CenterY="10"
                                     Angle="0"/>
                </Image.RenderTransform>
                <Image.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Image.MouseEnter">
                        <BeginStoryboard   HandoffBehavior="Compose"  >
                            <Storyboard Name="myStoryBoard" >
                                <DoubleAnimation
                    Storyboard.TargetName="imgTransform"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Angle" 
                        By="90" Duration="0:0:.2" 
                        />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </Image>
```

> image\close.png  is my image and you can change into yours.

As you can test,it has a `duration` and will stop automatically.However you can get `StoryBoard` Object by its `Name` property in C# code and call `Stop` method on it.

Comment: it cant find Close_MouseLeftButtonDown do i have to add something else ?

Comment: @FriedSloth You can simply remove this property because it is used for click event

Comment: The code was really usefull.I will try to change it a bit and post my result later or tomorrow.

Comment: @FriedSloth glad to help you and you may vote this answer up ,thk